# Using Matplotlib axes in more than one class method

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm writing a script to plot the brightness of objects as they vary with time in some combination of 6 filters.  I have both raw data and fits to the data and I want to be able to toggle plotting them on and off.  I've written a class for each object and then within that methods to create a) the axes, b) plot the raw data c) plot the model fits.  It looks something like:

```
    class SNPlot(object):
        def __init__(self, params):
            #initialise with various parameters

        def make_axes(self):

            gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3,2)

            #depending on what filters there are make various axes eg
            if ('B' in self.filters):
                ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0])

            #create ax1-ax6 if needed for the combination of filters

        def add_data(self):

            if ('B' in self.filters):
                ax1.plot(data[0], data[1], 'bo')

            #etc for all the different filters ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5 and ax6

        def add_model(self):

            if ('B' in self.filters):
                ax1.plot(model[0], model[1], 'b-')

            #etc for all the different filters ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5 and ax6


    def main():

        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Plot LCs for paper')
        parser.add_argument("-d", "--data", action='store_true', help = 'Plot LC data')
        parser.add_argument('-m', '--model', action='store_true',help='Plot model fits' )

        args = vars(parser.parse_args())

        sn = SNPlot(params)
        sn.make_axes()

        if (args[data] == True): sn.add_data
        if (args[model] == True): sn.add_model
```

When I try this with the -d option I get an error that `NameError: global name 'ax1' is not defined`.  How can I use ax1-6 in the other class methods?

Comment: Make `ax1` an attribute of the class: `self.ax1`. That should probably also hold for `fig`, since I don't see where that comes from.

Comment: Thanks!  That's great.  I did not know I could do that

Comment: Well, that's actually one of the things `self` is for: you can tie variables to it so that they can be used across different methods in a class; it basically works for anything, not just the "standard" Python variable types. Of course, if you have 6 `ax` objects, it's even easier to use `self.axes[0]`, `self.axes[1]` etc, instead of `self.ax1`, `self.ax2`. In that way, there's only one object that's an instance attribute (a list, though that contains 6 objects in itself).